# 成語 with 鮑魚, grammar structure?

Tags: chengyu

I stumbled upon this 成語：

```
如入鮑魚之肆久而不聞其臭。
it's like staying in a fish market and getting used to the stink    
long exposure to bad surroundings or bad company accustoms one to evil ways    
(source of translation: pleco dict)
```

My question is: what is the grammar of the sentence?

Is 入...之 a connecting structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 如{[(入<鮑魚之肆>)久]而[不(聞<其臭>)]}。
>
> It's like {[(having entered < a market of fish >) for long time] hence [can't (smell < its stink >)]}.

The root level is V-O '如...' (it's like ...), 如 is the verb.

Then 入鮑魚之肆久而不聞其臭 is Phrase-Conj-Phrase '...而...' (... hence ...), where 而 is the conjunction.

入鮑魚之肆久 is S-V, where 入鮑魚之肆 is 'V-O as Subject', 久 is the verb.

In 入鮑魚之肆, 入 is the verb (to enter), 鮑魚之肆 is noun phrase as the Object. 之 means 'of', 鮑魚之肆 means 'market of fishes'.